# Find the Residue of $\frac{e^z}{\sin^2(z)}$ at each finite singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The problem states:

> Find the Residue of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sin ^2(z)}$ at each finite singularity.

The poles are clearly at $z=k\pi (k\in\mathbb{Z})$, and the order are all 2, since:

$\lim_{z \to k\pi} (z-k\pi)\frac{e^z}{\sin ^2(z)}$ does not exists, and:

$\lim_{z \to k\pi} (z-k\pi)^2\frac{e^z}{\sin ^2(z)} = e^{k\pi}$

But when I try to find the residue, first I found I can't use known series expension formula ($\sin (z)$ in the denominator). Then I tried the formula:

$\lim_{z\to \pi k} \, \frac{d\left(f(z) (z-\pi k)^2\right)}{dz^1}$

= $\lim_{z\to \pi k} \, \left( 2(z-k\pi)\frac{e^z}{\sin ^2(z)} + (z-k\pi)^2 \frac{e^z(\sin ^2(z)-2\sin (z)\cos (z)) } {\sin ^4(z)} \right)$

(Pull out the middle term)

= $\lim_{z\to \pi k} \, \left( (z-k\pi)^2 \frac{e^z\sin ^2(z) } {\sin ^4(z)} \right)$
$+$ $ \lim_{z\to \pi k} \, \left( 2(z-k\pi)\frac{e^z}{\sin ^2(z)} + (z-k\pi)^2 \frac{e^z2\sin (z)\cos (z) } {\sin ^4(z)} \right) $

The left limit as calculated before is $e^{k\pi}$. The right one, although I did not do it myself at first, is confirmed by Mathematica to be zero.

However, when I tried to do the right limit myself, I found that I had to use L'Hôpital's rule for at least 3 times to calculate the limit. This made the calculation too cumbersome.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you seen the Residue Theorem? Contour integration is usually the best way to solve these sorts of problems, since for more complex expressions, direct evaluation with limits and derivatives gets very messy.

Comment: When I tried the integration, I replace $z$ with $e^{i\theta}+k\pi$, then in the integrand I have $e^{e^{i\theta}+k\pi}$, and $sin^2(e^{i\theta}+k\pi)$. They made it even more diffcult to deal with than the limit. I'm used to calculate integration by residue and had few experience in direct integration. @Dorebell

Comment: Try other contour shapes. Perhaps a rectangular contour. Sometimes its helpful to let one dimension go to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The solutioin provided by my teacher is:

First replace the variable $z$ with $t=z-n\pi$:

$\frac{e^z}{sin^2(z)}=\frac{2e^z}{1-cos(2z)}=(t=z-n\pi)\frac{2e^{t+n\pi}}{1-cos(2(t+n\pi))}=\frac{2e^{t+n\pi}}{1-cos(2t)}$

Then expand the function:

$\frac{2e^{t+n\pi}}{1-cos(2t)}=\frac{2e^{n\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}}{-\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(2t)^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$

Finding the coeficient (use the [Cauchy Product Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)) of $\frac{1}{t}$ is $e^{n\pi}$, which is the residue we wanted.